# MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen lockup

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, gestures

I have a strange bug regarding the `MPMoviePlayerController`.  If I do a reverse pinch gesture, (move two touch locations apart), while a video is playing (landscape), the video switches to portrait mode, broadcasts a `MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification` and a `MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification`, and is then stuck.

No touches seems to be registered after this point and the video is 'stuck' playing until it has finished.  Upon relaunching the `MPMoviePlayerController`, video fails and I am presented with a black screen.

I have tried forcing the video to leave fullscreen mode as soon as it received a `MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification` without any luck.

I have also tried to implement a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` on the player's view, but was unable to capture any gestures...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing controlStyle property to MPMovieControlStyleNone?